# Slow boot in elementary/ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, nvidia, amd

I'm running elementary OS (based on Ubuntu) and I've had this same problem also when running Ubuntu. Basically it just takes a hell of a long time to boot into the Linux system while booting into Windows is almost instant.

- Ryzen 7 1700
- ASUS x370 prime PRO
- 16GB G.Skill Trident Z, unsure what model they were though.
- Samsung 960 1TB NVME <- m2 slot
- Samsung 970 1TB NVME <- PCIE m2 extension board thing
- Nvidia 1080ti

Don't remember which drive I put which OS on.

I checked `dmesg` and found these huge gaps in time:

```
[    8.545104] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    8.545105] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[    8.637114] EDAC amd64: Node 0: DRAM ECC disabled.
[    8.637115] EDAC amd64: ECC disabled in the BIOS or no ECC capability, module will not load.
                Either enable ECC checking or force module loading by setting 'ecc_enable_override'.
                (Note that use of the override may cause unknown side effects.)
[   96.432885] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   96.432886] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   96.432890] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   96.611555] aufs 4.x-rcN-20190805
[   97.151046] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than PCI Bus 0000:00 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff window]
[   97.151156] caller os_map_kernel_space.part.13+0x6d/0x80 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
[   98.836517] usb 1-7.1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[   99.344878] igb 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: igb: enp8s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
[   99.452288] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp8s0: link becomes ready
[   99.647125] kauditd_printk_skb: 24 callbacks suppressed
[   99.647126] audit: type=1400 audit(1588497914.089:36): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=2005 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   99.698473] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   99.699382] Bridge firewalling registered
[   99.702361] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 2029
[   99.732583] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[  103.373584] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  103.373591] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  103.373597] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  114.773047] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  114.920620] usb 1-7.1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  120.030678] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
[  150.533181] gala[2619]: segfault at 188 ip 00007ff3c5713a00 sp 00007ffd14dcebc8 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7ff3c566a000+159000]
[  150.533194] Code: 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 47 50 c3 90 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 8b 87 90 00 00 00 c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 <f6> 87 88 01 00 00 08 75 07 48 8b 47 38 c3 66 90 48 8b 47 20 48 8b
[  209.536663] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[  209.543431] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[  209.553170] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[  209.568727] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what's going on here and what I can do to fix this?

I'm grateful for any help!

EDIT: Add lsblk and free -h

```
loop0                       7:0    0 707,1M  1 loop /snap/android-studio/88
loop1                       7:1    0 142,9M  1 loop /snap/code/31
loop2                       7:2    0  93,8M  1 loop /snap/core/8935
loop3                       7:3    0  54,8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop4                       7:4    0  93,9M  1 loop /snap/core/9066
loop5                       7:5    0  27,1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/7264
loop6                       7:6    0 160,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop7                       7:7    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop8                       7:8    0 140,2M  1 loop /snap/code/30
loop9                       7:9    0 700,5M  1 loop /snap/android-studio/87
loop10                      7:10   0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop11                      7:11   0 163,7M  1 loop /snap/spotify/41
loop12                      7:12   0    27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/6953
loop13                      7:13   0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1754
sda                         8:0    0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sda1                      8:1    0   1,8T  0 part 
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0 931,5G  0 part 
  ├─elementary--vg-root   253:0    0 930,4G  0 lvm  /
  └─elementary--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
nvme1n1                   259:2    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1               259:3    0   529M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p2               259:4    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3               259:5    0    16M  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p4               259:6    0 930,9G  0 part
```

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        3,2G        9,2G        436M        3,2G         11G
Swap:          975M          0B        975M
```

Edit: Add bluetooth logs

```
touko 03 12:20:26 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
touko 03 12:20:26 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Starting SDP server
touko 03 12:20:26 rob dbus-daemon[1251]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=0 pid=1202 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
touko 03 12:20:26 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
touko 03 12:20:27 rob NetworkManager[1281]: <info>  [1588497627.0569] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
touko 03 12:20:34 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:20:34 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:20:36 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:20:36 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.48 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:20:38 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:20:38 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:22:57 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Terminating
touko 03 12:22:57 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:22:57 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:22:57 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Stopping SDP server
touko 03 12:22:57 rob bluetoothd[1202]: Exit
touko 03 12:25:10 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
touko 03 12:25:10 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Starting SDP server
touko 03 12:25:10 rob dbus-daemon[1216]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=0 pid=1170 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
touko 03 12:25:10 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
touko 03 12:25:10 rob NetworkManager[1248]: <info>  [1588497910.9926] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
touko 03 12:25:17 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:25:17 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:25:28 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:25:28 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.47 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 12:25:34 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 12:25:34 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.72 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 13:00:09 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Unable to get connect data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
touko 03 13:00:20 rob bluetoothd[1170]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_CC_98_8B_56_78_E6/fd0: fd(27) ready
touko 03 13:48:00 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.209 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 13:48:00 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.209 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
touko 03 13:48:00 rob bluetoothd[1170]: RFCOMM server failed for Headset Voice gateway: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
touko 03 13:48:00 rob bluetoothd[1170]: RFCOMM server failed for :1.209/Profile/HSPHSProfile/00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb: rfcomm_bind: Address already in use (98)
touko 03 13:48:01 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Unable to connect Headset Voice gateway: connect: Device or resource busy (16)
touko 03 13:48:01 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Connecting Headset Voice gateway failed: Input/output error
touko 03 14:02:22 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.209 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
touko 03 14:02:22 rob bluetoothd[1170]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.209 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
```

Comment: Check swap space by `free -h` the block devices by `lsblk`, add these to your post

Comment: There, added those

Comment: gala crashed ,  You are not alone https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/766         and i believe something with bluetooth `journalctl | grep -i blue` try bootoption `edac_report=off`  between EDAC and bluetooth is a time hole `8.637115] EDAC amd64 [   96.432885] Bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

See where the issue lies by running `systemd analyze-blame`; also, update your BIOS. That fixed mine.